# How to click the first link with pdf content

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am new to selenium and python I wanted to get the url of the first link with the pdf.So I tried

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/mac/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://google.com/search?query=" + searchList[i])
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.sFZIhb.b.w.xsm").click()
url = driver.current_url
print(url)
```

But this does not click on the link .The pdf element span is "span.sFZIhb.b.w.xsm" it identifies but not clicking on the link.Any help is appreciated

Comment: Fix code formatting. Also note that `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 9)` line has no affect on next *link clicking* line

Comment: What is `searchList[i]` exactly? What is your exact _usecase_?

Comment: @DebanjanB searchList[i] is the search term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @InfernO 's XPath here is a snip that gets all the URL's and clicks the first one:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--incognito")
searchList = ["pdf example", "pdf file"]
urls = []
for i, word in enumerate(searchList):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\workspace\TalSolutionQA\general_func_class\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
    driver.get("https://google.com/search?query=" + searchList[i])
    all_urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '.pdf')]")
    urls.append([i.get_attribute("href") for i in all_urls])
    print(f'the urls:{[i.get_attribute("href") for i in all_urls]}')
    all_urls[0].click()
    driver.quit()

print(urls)
```

Welcome to selenium lots of fun awaits you!

Answer (score 2):

Getting first link that contains url with .pdf and clicking it.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '.pdf')])[1]").click();
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the index 1 in your XPath when using `.find_element_*`... it's only going to return the first one anyway.

Comment: I got the error SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[contains(@href, '.pdf')])[1]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: @Ricky , `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '.pdf')]").click()`